# Music management software that sync playlists onto Android device

Tags: software-rec, synchronization, android, music-player

I am trying to find a music management software that can sync playlists onto my Android phone running Cyanogenmod 9. BTW, this handset does not have an Internet connection.

Specifically, I want the device to appear in the software so that I can drag and drop a playlist into it. When this happens, I want the software to not only copy the songs over, but the *playlist* itself (whether a cue sheet, m3u, or something like that). The more seamless the integration the better.

This way, the music player on my handset can start playing the playlist right away and I won't have to reconstruct the list.

My search so far seems to indicate Rythmbox and Amarok can do this (can someone confirm?), but are there any others? I would like to know what my choices are before settling on one music manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Amarok does have very good integration wind sync with Android phones.

However, depending on your choice of DE, you may want to go with Rythmbox, since Amarok pulls in a lot of KDE libs along with itself.

You may also want to check out `mpd`, the "Music Player Daemon". Remote clients for MPD are available, as are clients for live streaming to your Android Phone. You should also be able to find one that will sync up with your phone.
There is this [script on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/1805933) that you may want to try. However, it uses rsync and I think ssh on the device for syncing. I haven't tried using the script in the past, so I cannot take guarantees for how it works.
Since it's a script, you can always hack it up a bit to make the changes you want very easily.

When you say, you don't have an internet connection on your phone, I assume you are trying to imply that the sync will be done through a wired connection.

Comment: Good to know both Rythmbox and Amarok should work fine. As for MPD, do you mean the script will synchronise music and playlists onto my Android device, so I can listen to them on my handset *without* streaming from the MPD server (i.e. offline)?

Comment: That is what the script claims to do.

Answer (score 1):

Rhythmbox's sync is garbage. Sync your entire colleciton or make a playlist for each album. It's clearly a feature that the developers don't really use. Other than that, Rhythmbox is pretty good.

Comment: While opinions are not inherently problematic, linking to sources that back up the defects you mention is far more convincing and useful.

Comment: I agree, can you elaborate on how Rhythmbox's sync is problematic? Thanks!